# Lipschitz condition and lipschitz continuity.

Tags: lipschitz-functions

Is there a difference between the Lipschitz condition with Lipschitz continuity? What is that difference if there is the difference?

Comment: None. Different phrase for the same thing. Remember that Lipschitz continuity imposes a bound on the size of the slopes of a function.

Comment: I have a bad case of the Lipschitz condition, but I find a glass or two of wine helps me escape the bounds.